# Why would one want to learn and/or practice using servers with Java SE, over using the EE approach?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I think I have a basic understanding of why, but I can't articulate the reasoning. If I understand correctly, doesn't SE use sockets, streams etc, while EE (servlets etc) basically "does all that work for you", so to speak? In other words, aren't they more or less doing the same thing, but it just helps to understand the underlying process via SE servers..?

Comment: Are you referring to servers based on Spring vs "orthodox" JavaEE servers?

Comment: No, I'm taking a Java II class at my CS University and one of our assignments is in regards to a Java SE server. We're doing the assignment with an SE server to emphasize why EE is useful.

Answer (score 3):

It's always useful to understand what's going on at a lower level:

1. you may want to use some approach not catered for by standard EE application servers (e.g. you may want to make use of something like [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/), or code a trivial client/server that doesn't need the EE overhead)
2. You may need to debug or otherwise troubleshoot your application server. Under the covers it'll being using sockets etc. and simply wrapping those in some 'friendly' APIs and frameworks.

If you have that fundamental understanding you can understand what's going on, the limitations of chosen solutions, how to improve on them, and translate the concepts into different platforms and languages.

Comment: I don't know where I read it, but someone said that you should always understand what's going on at least one layer of abstraction below where you're working.